# Looping through an array that is part of a larger function

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm trying to scrape the same data off multiple pages of a website. The url links are all in a json document as an array. I can't figure out how to loop through each website link and grab data from each page. I feel like I need to make a loop for the entire function but I want to make sure the data all ends up in the same file. Here's what I have thus far...

```
const fs = require('fs');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function extractItems() {
  const extractedElements = document.querySelectorAll('#MoreInfoPanel_81 > div.more-info-panel-body');
  const items = [];
  for (let element of extractedElements) {
    items.push(element.innerText);
  }
  return items;
}

async function scrapeItems(
  page,
  extractItems,
  itemCount,
  scrollDelay = 800,
) {
  let items = [];
  try {
    let previousHeight;
    while (items.length < itemCount) {
      items = await page.evaluate(extractItems);
      previousHeight = await page.evaluate('document.body.scrollHeight');
      await page.evaluate('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)');
      await page.waitForFunction(`document.body.scrollHeight > ${previousHeight}`);
      await page.waitForTimeout(scrollDelay);
    }
  } catch(e) { }
  return items;
}

function hospitalLinks() {
  let dataFile = require('./hospitallinks.json');
  for (let i = 0; i < dataFile.length; i++) {
  }
}

(async () => {
  // Set up Chromium browser and page.
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 926 });

  // Navigate to the page.
  await page.goto(hospitalLinks());

  // Auto-scroll and extract desired items from the page.
  const items = await scrapeItems(page, extractItems, 4908);

  // Save extracted items to a new file.
  fs.writeFileSync('./facilitydata.txt', items.join('\n') + '\n');

  // Close the browser.
  await browser.close();
})();
```

It works if I replace the `hospitalLinks()` with a url...I tried using `forEach` but it didn't work either.

Comment: What does `hospitalLinks()` do?

Comment: i recommended using Promise.all.